# Choose dropdown option based on input box option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following box which is just a text box for a month in number for. ie January is 01

```
<input type="text" name="ccnum" id="em">
```

I need a way for my dropdown box to select the month name, so if 01 is in the text box, January would be selected, and so on.

```
<select class="form-dropdown validate[required] cc_exp_month" name="q6_invoiceAmount[cc_exp_month]" id="input_6_cc_exp_month" data-component="cc_exp_month">
  <option> </option> 
  <option value="January"> January </option> 
  <option value="February"> February </option> 
  <option value="March"> March </option> 
  <option value="April"> April </option> 
  <option value="May"> May </option>
  <option value="June"> June </option> 
  <option value="July"> July </option> 
  <option value="August"> August </option> 
  <option value="September"> September </option> 
  <option value="October"> October </option> 
  <option value="November"> November </option> 
  <option value="December"> December </option> 
</select>
```

Tried this code below but that's specific to same type in both boxes

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=selectNow]').on('click', function(event) {
        selectByText($.trim($('input[name=selText]').val()));
    }).click();

    $('input[name=selText]').on('keyup', function() {
        selectByText($.trim($(this).val()));
    });
});

function selectByText(txt) {
    $('#MySelect option')
        .filter(function() { 
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == txt; 
        })
        .attr('selected', true);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or wait for us to write you code?

Comment: Tried this code which im editing

Comment: @MHeredia -> here is example for You -> https://jsfiddle.net/ifinto/o2gxgz9r/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `number` of the each month as `options` value and bind event listener to the `input`.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var box = document.getElementById('em'),
    select = document.getElementById('input_6_cc_exp_month');

  box.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    select.value = this.value;
  });

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ccnum" id="em" />

<select class="form-dropdown validate[required] cc_exp_month" name="q6_invoiceAmount[cc_exp_month]" id="input_6_cc_exp_month" data-component="cc_exp_month">
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 <option value="3">March</option> 
 <option value="4">April</option> 
 <option value="5">May</option> 
 <option value="6">June</option>
 <option value="7">July</option>
 <option value="8">August</option> 
 <option value="9">September</option>
 <option value="10">October</option>
 <option value="11">November</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Seems like this will work but im getting this error in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @MHeredia Make sure that you typed `id` attribute correctly and you are importing the script at the bottom of the `body` tag.

Comment: Works on the code snippet. Is there a specific jquery version to use?

Comment: @MHeredia It's pure javascript, you don't need jQuery.

Comment: Got it working. Only issue now is that I'm using this with a credit card usb swiper. It works if I type in 01 in my text box and it changes the drop down. But if I swipe it doesn't.

Comment: @MHeredia So maybe it's better to use it from `0` to `12` instead of `01` to `12`?

Comment: Tried that. If I go back to the text field and click around it changes. That text field is going to be hidden. So seems like there needs to be an action after

Comment: looks like it just needs to reload that text box or something or run that code twice

Comment: @MHeredia Im not really sure what's the problem... it works fine in the snippet, I dont know how does your *credit card usb swiper* works :(

Answer (score 0):

Because your month options have index ranging from 1 to 12 it's enough to test the input value against NaN or a value outside the range.

```js
$('input[name=ccnum]').on('input', function(e) {
    var idx = +this.value;  // get current input value as number
    if (!isNaN(idx)) { // if number
        if (idx > 12) {  // if greater than 12
            idx = 12;
        }
        if (idx < 1) { // if smaller than 1
            idx = 1;
        }
        this.value = idx;
        // select the corresponding option by index
        $('#input_6_cc_exp_month option').eq(idx).prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        // if NaN remove non numeric values
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]*/g, '');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="ccnum" id="em">
<select class="form-dropdown validate[required] cc_exp_month" name="q6_invoiceAmount[cc_exp_month]"
        id="input_6_cc_exp_month" data-component="cc_exp_month">
    <option> </option>
    <option value="January"> January </option>
    <option value="February"> February </option>
    <option value="March"> March </option>
    <option value="April"> April </option>
    <option value="May"> May </option>
    <option value="June"> June </option>
    <option value="July"> July </option>
    <option value="August"> August </option>
    <option value="September"> September </option>
    <option value="October"> October </option>
    <option value="November"> November </option>
    <option value="December"> December </option>
</select>
```